# send current line to external command in vim (without capture)

Tags: vim

The goal is to use the current line as a TODO and send this to some external program. Something like this:

```
:! /usr/bin/todo "content of current line"
```

I know of the filtering command but this implies that I want to edit the current buffer which I do not want (:.! acts as a filter). I know how to get the current file with '%' but isn't there any way to get some other content ? Maybe by using :execute ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`:.!` works as a filter, but `:.w !` (mind the space!) just passes the output. See `:help :w_c`. I.e.

```
:.w !/usr/bin/todo -
```

Comment: This is exactly what I searched for. I ended with a mapping like this map <Leader>ta :silent .w !todo<Return> to create a todo from the current line. Thanks !

Comment: i looked at and upvoted this answer because i was interested in doing something similar. to execute an external command on the file starting from the cursor position, i used :.,$w !command &

Comment: Doesn't work by me.
:.w !ls
ls: cannot access -: No such file or directory
shell returned 2

Comment: @ka3ak, it is not supposed to work with `ls`. What are you trying to achieve here? The `w` command sends data from buffer to the *standard input* of a command, but `ls` does *not* process standard input.

Comment: @JanHudec Sorry, if I've misunderstood the question and the answer. I want to pass current line contents to an external command as a parameter. In the example above, I wanted to pass a line which contains a file path to 'ls'.

Comment: @ka3ak, hm, I am not sure there is a command for it, but you could try `:.w !xargs ls`, utilizing the generic `xargs` command that converts input to command-line arguments.

Comment: @JanHudec Thanks! Your solution works but only with paths without spaces. I've solved it in the meanwhile with: exec(":!ls '".getline(".")."'")

Comment: @ka3ak, yes; a bit unwieldy, but that's the “correct” solution. The xargs can, however, be also made to work on names with spaces given suitable set of options (should be `-d '\n'`).

Comment: How do I search the docs for `:.w`? Typing `:help :.w` in Neovim finds nothing.  Ah, it's clearly a variant of `:w !{cmd}`, which I can find. What does the preceding period do? Ah, it's the 'current line' range. OK!

Answer (score 3):

You can insert contents of registers into command line, so doing something like:

```
"1y$  //yank current row to register 1
: CTRL-R 1  //CTRL-R followed by register id pastes register to command line
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You might like something like these mappings (i.e. saved in your `.vimrc` or pasted into a `:` prompt):

```
cmap <C-R>'           <C-R>=shellescape(getline('.'))<CR>
cmap <C-R><C-R>' <C-R><C-R>=shellescape(getline('.'))<CR>
```

Once installed, you use them like this:

```
:!/usr/bin/todo ^R'
```

(type an actual <kbd>Control</kbd>‑<kbd>R</kbd> where the above example shows `^R`).

You can think of them as command-line mode versions of the registere-based Control‑R and Control‑R Control‑R (see [`:help c_CTRL-R`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R), and [`:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-R`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-R)) where the “imaginary” register `'` always contains the shell-quoted contents of the current line.

Because these mappings use the same prefix as built-in mappings (see the `:help` topics mentioned above), you must enter the final single quote within `timeoutlen` milliseconds (see `:set timeoutlen?`), or it will default to the built-in mapping (see [`:help map-typing`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-typing)).